# How to specify path for local jars in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am using maven2 to build the java project. when I am trying to build using `mvn install`  I am getting the compilation error saying some  package `xya.abc.aaa` doesnot exist. This package is available in my own jar at local disk. This jar(say test.jar) is created by me.

How can I tell to maven to use this local jar for the package its looking for is availabe at my local disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [install the dependencies to your local repository](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars).

```
mvn install:install-file
  -Dfile=<path-to-file>
  -DgroupId=<group-id>
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
  -Dversion=<version>
  -Dpackaging=<packaging>
  -DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
       <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
       <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
       <version>       the version of the file
       <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```